# Can I select administrator info from Enterprise Box account?

Tags: box-api

We are integrating the Box into our application for iOS. We would like the user’s info – particularly user name. We use the method GET /users. It works well with private users and regular users on enterprise account, but is a bit inconvenient for enterprise administrator. We get the list of all the users in this account.

Is it possible to distinguish the particular administrator name from this list? Is it the first name in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
GET /users/{user id}
```

To get information of an individual user. Regarding whether you can distinguish an admin in the list, you cannot do that for now. Atleast, they do not support it for now

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add that the users endpoint is one for which the Box Platform team is still adding features before we take the V2 API out of beta.  Currently, you may find more possibilities with the V1 API, in particular, the get_account_info call.  However, it's best to use the V2 API as much as possible, since the V1 will be deprecated soon.